# Sort a html printed table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a table which has the following columns:

**SelectGroup,Rank,Crew Name,Status,Available Date,Document Monitoring,Documents**

the Rank, Crew Name, and status comes from a mysql query and it is then printed as a cell in the table.on the other hand, for the document monitoring, only the document_exp_date is retrieved by the mysql. then the difference between the current date and document_exp_date is computed using php. there will be three results:

```
NO DOCUMENTS EXPIRED
SOME DOCUMENTS ARE EXPIRING
SOME DOCUMENTS ARE EXPIRED
```

Now, I have a problem with sorting the table. it's easy to sort the rank and the status because it is in the database but we also need to sort it according to document monitoring. we want our output to be in this order:

```
MASTER, VACATION, NO DOCUMENTS EXPIRED
MASTER, VACATION, SOME DOCUMENTS ARE EXPIRING
MASTER, VACATION, SOME DOCUMENTS ARE EXPIRED
.
.
.
CHIEF MATE , VACATION, NO DOCUMENTS EXPIRED
CHIEF MATE , VACATION, SOME DOCUMENTS ARE EXPIRING
CHIEF MATE , VACATION, SOME DOCUMENTS ARE EXPIRED
```

I tried to include the computation for document monitoring in the query but the execution time is horrible. how can we sort the table?

Comment: You could store everything in an array before printing to HTML and then sorting the array with some of the php array sorting functions? Then afterwards you only print the array in html table?

Comment: store all your data into an array/list/datagrid and then sort that rather than sorting on mysql

Comment: do you mean all the retrieved data?

Comment: Please, share the slow query.

Comment: I believe i did say "store all of your data" by using the word all I mean all not just part